# VBA InStr Excel vs Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

The default InStr for Access seems to be vbTextCompare and for Excel seems to be vbBinaryCompare.

Can anyone confirm and/or shed light on why two different Microsoft products are handling the same code differently.

Comment: [Option Compare](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3992/vba-option-keyword/13937/option-compare-binary-text-database#t=201702071935413568219) on Documentation.SO.

Comment: `InStr` is defined in the VBA standard library, in the `Strings` module, and its comparison mode is an optional parameter with a default value. Are you saying this default value is different in MS-Access? [A screenshot of the IntelliSense for that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TT1WN.png) would be nice, for those of us who don't have MS-Access to test.

Comment: Are you running it via SQL in Access?  I.e.: `SELECT InStr(Foo,"text") AS Loc FROM Bar;`  I get identical results in Access and Excel.

Comment: @Comintern - nope, not in SQL. I changed my code to be more explicit and use the vbBinaryCompare

Comment: Yep, the default value is different in Access, depending upon whether you execute the statement in the Immediate Window or in a Code module. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR - In Access, the immediate window doesn't have a module-level `Option Compare` statement to honor, but defaults to a different default than Excel, and a different default to an Access module that doesn't include an `Option Compare` statement.**. Jump to the Conclusions for the specifics.

The `Option Compare` statement has Intellisense that *suggests* that the value must be a member of `VbCompareMethod`:

- `vbBinaryCompare = 0`
- `vbTextCompare = 1`
- `vbDatabaseCompare = 2` 'Runtime error 5 if used in non-Access VBA

However, the Microsoft documentation for [`InStr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/D83B314A-E77C-FC18-0744-266F982A82B7(Office.15).aspx) goes further and specifies that the value of `Compare` may also be `vbUseCompareOption = -1`, but `vbUseCompareOption` isn't in the Object Browser, and resolves to an undeclared `Empty` in the Immediate window in both Excel and Access:

```
?IsEmpty(vbUseCompareOption)
True
```

Furthermore, trying to use a literal value of `-1` as the `Compare` argument results in `Runtime error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument`, so clearly the **documentation isn't for trusting**.

And trying to use `vbUseCompareOption` in a module with `Option Explicit` set results in `Compile Error: Variable not defined`, so relaxing the `Option Explicit` rule, allows the following 2 lines to be equivalent:

```
strcomp("A", "a", vbUseCompareOption)
strcomp("A", "a", Empty)
```

The documentation also says that you can provide a locale ID, for example: `1033` for US-English, or `1036` for France-French. I don't know of any collation differences between English and French to test, but there may be some for various codepages, and it's worth noting that SQL Server collation isn't the same as Windows collation, so it seems likely that Access collation is not the same as Windows location either. See [Collation Types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175194(v=sql.105).aspx).

It seems likely that VBA's `vbTextCompare` uses Windows (or a VBA-flavored) collation, and `vbDatabaseCompare` (and *possibly* providing a locale ID) performs an Access-flavored SQL collation. Your Access database has a collation property that can be read with `CurrentDb.CollatingOrder`, and only set when used as an argument to `DBEngine.CompactDatabase`. It seems likely that VBA uses that `CollatingOrder` Locale ID when performing a `vbDatabaseCompare`

### Implicit Compare

But it's not clear what the default value is, so you're correct, Excel and Access exhibit different behaviors in the Immediate window, when omitting the `Compare` argument:

```
'Excel
?strcomp("A","a")
-1 

'Access
?strcomp("A","a")
0
```

### Explicit Compare

But they share identical results when the `Compare` argument is supplied with a value of `vbBinaryCompare` or `vbTextCompare`

```
'Excel
?strcomp("A","a",vbBinaryCompare)
-1 
?strcomp("A","a",vbTextCompare)
0 

'Access
?strcomp("A","a",vbBinaryCompare)
-1 
?strcomp("A","a",vbTextCompare)
0
```

Now, let's see what happens with each of Access's `Option Compare` settings in a module with various settings for the Access module's `Option Compare`.

```
                                       Compare Not | Compare  | Compare | Compare
Statement                            | specified   | Database | Binary  | Text   | Excel
StrComp("A", "a")                    |     -1      |     0    |   -1    |   0    |  -1
StrComp("A", "a", Empty)             |     -1      |    -1    |   -1    |  -1    |  -1
StrComp("A", "a", vbDatabaseCompare) |      0      |     0    |    0    |   0    | Error
StrComp("A", "a", vbBinaryCompare)   |     -1      |    -1    |   -1    |  -1    |  -1
StrComp("A", "a", vbTextCompare)     |      0      |     0    |    0    |   0    |   0
```

### Observations

- When a `Compare` argument is not passed to `StrComp`, the Access results are consistent with Excel, *only* when `Option Compare` either isn't specified, or is specified as `Option Compare Binary`
- When a `Compare` argument is not passed to `StrComp`, the Access results are inconsistent with Excel, as we'd expect, *only* when Access' `Option Compare` is set as either `Option Compare Text` or `Option Compare Database`
- When a `Compare` argument is passed to `StrComp`, the results are consistent across Access and Excel, with the exception of the Error when `vbDatabaseCompare` is used with Excel.
- When a `Compare` argument value of `Empty` is passed to `StrComp`, the result is consistent with an implicit default of `vbBinaryCompare`. **Yet another argument for using `Option Explicit`**, as passing an undeclared/unassigned variable will potentially produce unexpected results.
- The results in Access are different between code executed in the Immediate Window and code executed in a Module with an `Option Compare` statement.

### Conclusions

- In Access, code evaluated in the Immediate Window that omits the `Compare` argument in a call to `StrComp`, will default to *Text* Compare.
- In Access, code executed from within a module that omits the `Compare` argument in a call to `StrComp`, will default to the `Option Compare` setting in *that* module. If an `Option Compare` statement isn't present, the module will default to *Binary*, just like Excel.
- In non-Access VBA hosts (such as Excel), *all* code that omits an optional `Compare` argument, will default to *Binary* Compare.

Answer (score 3):

The `InStr` function is a `Variant`-returning function that lives in the `Strings` module of the VBA standard library `VBE7.DLL`, which is included in every VBA project, regardless of the host.

[image: InStr in Excel]

When the optional parameter isn't specified, it takes its default value, which is `vbBinaryCompare`:

[image: IntelliSense]

Now, this is in Excel and I don't have MS-Access to test, but unless MS-Access ships with a custom-compiled VBA7.DLL standard library (*slightly* unlikely), the function's signature would be identical, which means the function behaves exactly the same in all VBA host applications.

[image: in object browser]

---

Other than that, string comparisons are driven by a module option, `Option Compare`, which in MS-Access defaults to `Option Compare Database`, and in other hosts defaults to `Option Compare Binary`. All the information about that module option is available on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266181(v=vs.60).aspx).